# Where is my servers IP on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have just started working with Amazon Web Services and I set up my first instance.  I just installed apache but now I'd like to test if the install was successful.  I can't seem to find where my servers IP address is.  Do you know where I need to look for this?

[image]

UPDATE:

I'm still not seeing it.  Maybe I'm blind.  All I see is Private IPs.

Comment: You need to allocate an external IP address and then assign it.

Comment: @vcsjones With the exception of instances launched in vpc. All instances automatically get a public ip address.

Comment: You did connect to the instance to install apache. Use the same ip address to see if its working.

Comment: @datasage - I didn't use the ip to connect to apache.  I used the public DNS which when entered into my browser returns nothing.  I'm not that great at this server stuff.

Comment: @JasonBiondo The public DNS maps to the public IP (The name indicates the ip address). If you didn't get anything, either your security group is not configured to allow traffic on port 80, or your apache install is not running.

Comment: @datasage Thank you.  It was a security group issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your instance via the public DNS value shown.  The public DNS value will actually hint at the public IP address of the instance, as those are the for numbers shown in the name.

If you want a static IP address (i.e. you can re-use the same IP after instance restarts), then you would need to allocate an elastic IP and attach it to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html
Under "Determining Your Public and Private IP Addresses"

Comment: Those docs don't make sense to me.  I read them, but I still don't know what I am missing.